# usleep() locks the iPhone prompting

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

I am using `CLLocationManager`, if the program is installed for the first time, it requires user to accept or deny to share his location. What I want is to program itself to wait until user prompts.

Now the issue is I am waiting there with `usleep()`

```
while ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == USER_NOT_PROMPTED) {
    usleep(10000);
}
```

But this causes the actual iPhone to be locked in a way that the location sharing question does not pop up, therefore the program hangs. Is there a way to run those user prompts in a separate thread? I am using iOS 6.1

Comment: No, you cannot access the internal behavior of a library and even if you could, you can't perform UI interaction on a separate thread.  You need to rethink your logic instead.  If the user accepts, your CLLocationManager will start as usual.  If it fails, then you will get the callback `didFailWithError:`

Comment: Then it's a good practise to run the entire program in a separate process or thread?

Comment: Your program will have no concept of processes.  You need to be more specific because the answer to the above question is "probably not"

Comment: Basically, I do not want user to do anything before the location services prompt pops up.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is freezing because you're blocking the run loop, which makes it impossible for the system to prompt the user for permission to use location. **Don't do that.** If you want the user to allow or deny use of their location right away, just make a location manager call early in your app. If you don't want the user to be able to do anything else before they decide, don't give them anything to do -- show a blank screen, perhaps.

That doesn't sound like a good user experience, though, so it'd be better to find a way to let them do as much as possible. Why not just assume that the user is denying you permission to use their location until they've decided otherwise?